# Apache camel connecting to redirected ftp

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I have the following simple camel program trying to poll a ftp server for files

```
public class GetFilesFromFtp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        public void configure() {
            from("ftp://<USER>@f<FTPHOST>/<FOLDER>?password=<PASSWORD>&passiveMode=true")
                .to("file:data/outbox");
        }
    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    context.stop();

  }

}
```

The program works fine on one ftp server, but failes on another. I have checked the permissions on the folders on the ftp server and they are OK. I suspect that the problem might be, that the ftp server (Titan) is redirecting to another file server, but I don't know how to get arround that. The error i get looks like this:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550 Requested action not taken, file not found or no access.
 Cannot change directory to: /. Code: 550
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.doChangeDirectory(FtpOperations.java:705) ~[camel-ftp-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(FtpOperations.java:668) ~[camel-ftp-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.pollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:53) ~[camel-ftp-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:107) ~[camel-core-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:142) [camel-core-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92) [camel-core-2.10.5.jar:2.10.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_10]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `stepWise=false` on the ftp endpoint.

See more details about this option at

- http://camel.apache.org/ftp2